# How to change d path of a svg to flip the direction of the image?

Tags: svg

I have this d path for an svg but I want to flip the direction of the diagonal lines, how would I do that with this d path?

d:'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11'

I want to switch it to this direction?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsDpo.png)

Comment: add transform="scale(1, -1)" or something similar.

Comment: I mean using the path

Comment: Why? My suggestion achieves what you asked for. If you want to draw a different path the other way round, use an SVG editor such as Inkscape.

Comment: I'm going to edit out the D tag because that is about the D programming language rather than the specific svg thingy.

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths to learn what the path commands mean.